# Laravel 9 - Docker - Windows - No puedo hacer llamadas Guzzle a localhost. Connection refused

Tags: laravel, docker, http, localhost, guzzle

Necesito hacer `Http:get('http://localhost:8080/api/test')` y me da este error:

```
   Illuminate\Http\Client\ConnectionException  cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://localhost:8080/api/test.
```

En cambio, si lo hago hacia google va OK :

```
> Http::get('http://www.google.com')
= Illuminate\Http\Client\Response {#4960
    +cookies: GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar {#4945},
    +transferStats: GuzzleHttp\TransferStats {#4986},
  }
```

He leido por ahi que es que la maquina de docker no consigue resolver localhost, y hay que hacer un proxy o algo pero no se muy bien a que se refiere, lo que he probado es a añadir esto en la **configuracion de mi docker dektop** :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero aun asi no funciona.

Comment: Si entiendo bien... esa llamada guzzle la estas haciendo desde un contenedor docker, pero el localhost al que queres acceder es el del anfitrion? O está en el mismo contenedor esa api?

Comment: Claro, el docker esta bindeado a mi ´localhost:8080´ para poder ver la app y tal, pero a nivel de codigo le estoy diciendo esa misma IP , y puede que este ahi el fallo. La idea es todo desde el contenedor : que haga un guzzle a si mismo, que no se que host tendria que poner si quiero hacerlo de forma interna. @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Ah, ok. Entonces prueba sin el puerto, directamente a localhost: `Http:get('http://localhost/api/test')`, el puerto es para cuando accedes desde el anfitrion

Comment: Gracias ! Eso era